# Get One Element From ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a custom object defined here:

```
public class ContactObject {

    public String contactName;
    public String contactNo;
    public String image;
    public boolean selected;

    public String getName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setNumber(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

And I have populated an ArrayList of this custom object (binderContacts) but now I want to convert this to a normal ArrayList with a list of all the contactNo's in my array list. Can someone help here?

```
public class ContactsListClass {

    public static final ArrayList<ContactObject> phoneList = new ArrayList<ContactObject>();
    public static final ArrayList<ContactObject> binderContacts = new ArrayList<ContactObject>();
}
```

Comment: Your title doesn't make much sense. ArrayList which stores elements of some type is still ArrayList. Please correct it to better describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also fields in ContactObject class should most probably be private, not public.

Comment: Another thing is that you should prefer to [program on interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) rather then its specific implementation. So your `phoneList` and `binderContacts` should be of type `List<ContactObject>`, not `ArrayList<ContactObject>`. This will give you more flexibility in case you would want to use other list than ArrayList.

Comment: I edited the title - this is probably why I can't find the answer (because I am confused about arraylists/objects in general at the moment). What I want to do is take from the ArrayList<ContactObject> binderContacts and convert it to an ArrayList<String> with just phone numbers

Comment: Create empty ArrayList<String>, iterate over your already filled ArrayList<ContactObject> and for each ContactObject read its contactNo and add it to that new ArrayList<String>.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java 8:

```
ArrayList<String> contactNos = binderContacts.stream().map(contact -> contact.getNumber()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `binderContacts.stream().map(ContactObject::getNumber).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: `map(contact -> contact.getNumber())` returns `Stream` not `List`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, however I am developing an Android app and therefore am using Java 7

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> contactNos = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ContactObject o : phoneList) {
    contactNos.add(o.getNumber());
}
```